# Unable to convert a csv file to a java object

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

I am using Springboot for my web application. There is one API endpoint which consumes a multipart csv file. I am supposed to read this file and then map it to my user java class and then store it in the db.
My Controller class

```
@PostMapping(value = "/students" ,consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public void registerStudents(@Valid @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
    if(file.isEmpty())
        throw new Exception("File is Empty!");
    registrationService.registerStudents(file);
}
```

My RegistrationService class

```
 public void registerStudents(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    CsvToBean<PlatformUser> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<PlatformUser>();
    HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<PlatformUser> strategy = new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<PlatformUser>();
    strategy.setType(PlatformUser.class);
    File convertedFile = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()));
    file.transferTo(convertedFile);
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(convertedFile));
    List<PlatformUser> userList = csvToBean.parse(strategy,csvReader);
}
```

My csv file is

```
FIRST NAME,MIDDLE NAME,LAST NAME
Rajeev,K,Hegde
```

My PlatformUser class is

```
@CsvBindByName(column = "FIRST NAME", required = true)
private String firstName;

@Size(max = 30)
@CsvBindByName(column = "MIDDLE NAME")
private String middleName;

@Size(max = 30)
@CsvBindByName(column = "LAST NAME", required = true)
private String lastName;
```

Below is my postman response to my api call

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-05-01T13:21:27.882+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.getAllFields(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;",
"path": "/api/v1/registration/students"
```

}

When i tried to debug my application i found out that line strategy.setType(PlatformUser.class); in RegistrationService is throwing error 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
For a clear picture adding my stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils.getAllFields(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;
at com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.loadFields(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:373) ~[opencsv-4.0.jar:na]
at com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.loadFieldMap(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:319) ~[opencsv-4.0.jar:na]
at com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.setType(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:408) ~[opencsv-4.0.jar:na]
at com.pqube.core.services.RegistrationService.registerStudents(RegistrationService.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
at com.pqube.core.controllers.RegistrationAPI.registerStudents(RegistrationAPI.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at com.pqube.core.security.filter.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Can someone please help here.

Comment: Add the actual stacktrace to your post.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: That clearly shows you are using incompatible versions of Commons Lang.

Comment: @M.Deinum
Should I go for some other version of opencsv(latest one 4.1???). 
Or is there any other better alternative through which this can be done?